# Filter chain halted as :validate_sign_up_params rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise

I am installing Devise to deploy Login function on Rails API as backend.

I tried to post API request by Postman but gets the following error.

[Error Message]
Unpermitted parameter: :format
Filter chain halted as :validate_sign_up_params rendered or redirected

・Request (Postman)：
POST "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth"

・json
{
"username": "hogehoge",
"email": "hogehoge@example.com",
"password": "123456789"
}

---

```
app / controllers / v1 / auth / registrations_controller.rb 
   module Api
      module V1
        module Auth
          class RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController
            private
            def sign_up_params
              params.permit(:username, :email, :password)
            end
            def account_update_params
              params.permit(:username, :email)
            end
    
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: postman settings]

On Postman, the format of sending data was just "Text", but changed to "JSON" like above, then the problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You should add `password_confirmation` parameter to your request.

Comment: I added "password_confirmation" but still get same error message. Thanks!

Comment: In permit param part you need permit it too

Comment: I added it in permit params as well, still not works. thanks!